# ggplot 5 minute datetime on x-axis

Tags: r

First question on stack overflow and first week of use of R. Very likely this question has been asked and answered and i simply do not know how to search for the answer. So please feel free to give me advice on how to search if that would be faster than answering the question.

Basic logging of datetime stamp in a sql table where a count of a number of things left to do in a queue. While a table works fine for me to see when the processing stalls a graph is necessary for some. Below is the code used to generate a graph which more or less works. It would be nice if on the x-axis we could rotate the datetime stamp 45 degrees (or so) and have every hour listed or maybe every three hours if hourly is crowded. On the y-axis we would like to add more ticks as well, maybe every 100 rather than every 500.

```
dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=*server*;database=*db*;trusted_connection=true')
res <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, "SELECT count, logged FROM table where logged > getdate()-1 order by logged desc")
ggplot(res, aes(x=logged,y=count))+geom_area(fill="blue", alpha=.2)+geom_line()+geom_point()
```

top three records to show the datetime format if it matters. (we do not need seconds or even minutes)
1331    2016-06-08 21:48:37.027
1359    2016-06-08 21:43:35.467
1416    2016-06-08 21:38:36.770

[image: https://db.tt/Qr0De48v]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: some reproducible data and code would be nice

Comment: examine the options behind `scale_continuous` and `scale_date`. See [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_continuous.html) and [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_date.html).

Comment: ggplot(res, aes(x=logged,y=subsect))+geom_area(fill="blue", alpha=.2)+geom_line()+geom_point()+scale_x_datetime(name = waiver(), date_breaks = "3 hours", date_labels = "%H:%M")

Thanks much the scale_x_datetime seems to work well. This doesn't rotate the text on the x axis for the 45 degree type thing but we have the space to fit what we need for now.